# how to send SMTP email in perl

Tags: perl, smtp

Below is what I wrote to send an email from my mailhost to my individual email address and the error I'm getting.

Could someone please help me with why we are getting the error:

> Can't call method "mail" on an undefined value at cmm_ping.pl line 2.

```
use Net::SMTP;
$smtp->mail("jo-sched@abcd.com");
$smtp->recipient("Myname@XXX-XXXX.com");
$smtp->datasend("From: jo-sched@abcd.com");
$smtp->datasend("To: Myname@xxxx-xxxxxx.com");
$smtp->datasend("Subject: This is a test");
$smtp->datasend("\n");
$smtp->datasend("This is a test");
$smtp->dataend;
$smtp->quit;
```

Comment: @flo, There's no need to add `** Edited for formatting` to a post you've edited. You do, however, have to do something else. If possible fix everything that's wrong with a post.

Comment: Please consider using a higher-level module like [Email::Sender](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Email::Sender) for sending email.  [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10008814/8355) from a previous question.

Comment: Also use strict; use warnings;

Answer (score 3):

The variable `$smtp` has not yet been defined. Take a look at the [usage examples of Net::SMTP](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/SMTP.html#EXAMPLES). This example pretty much does what your code shall do:

```
use Net::SMTP;

$smtp = Net::SMTP->new('mailhost');

$smtp->mail($ENV{USER});
$smtp->to('postmaster');

$smtp->data();
$smtp->datasend("To: postmaster\n");
$smtp->datasend("\n");
$smtp->datasend("A simple test message\n");
$smtp->dataend();

$smtp->quit;
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you familiar with how Object Oriented Perl works?

In order to use an object oriented Perl module, you have to first create an object of that class type. Normally, this is done via the `new` method:

```
my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new($mailhost);
```

Now, `$smtp` is an *object* of class `Net::SMTP`. Basically, it's a reference to a glob where you can store your data structure (who are you sending to, your message, etc.). Then Perl can use this information during method calls (which are just subroutines that are part of the package Net::SMTP).

Here's an example from a program I wrote:

```
use Net::SMTP;

my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new(
    Host  => $watch->Smtp_Host,
    Debug => $debug_level,
);

if ( not defined $smtp ) {
    croak qq(Unable to connect to mailhost "@{[$watch->Smtp_Host]}");
}

if ($smtp_user) {
    $smtp->auth( $watch->Smtp_User, $watch->Smtp_Password )
        or croak
        qq(Unable to connect to mailhost "@{[$watch->Smtp_Host]}")
        . qq( as user "@{[$watch->Smtp_User]}");
}

if ( not $smtp->mail( $watch->Sender ) ) {
    carp qq(Cannot send as user "@{[$watch->Sender]}")
        . qq( on mailhost "@{[$watch->Smtp_Host]}");
    next;
}
if ( not $smtp->to($email) ) {
    $smtp->reset;
    next;    #Can't send email to this address. Skip it
}

#
# Prepare Message
#
# In Net::SMTP, the Subject and the To fields are actually part
# of the message with a separate blank line separating the
# actual message from the header.
#
my $message = $watch->Munge_Message( $watcher, $email );
my $subject =
    $watch->Munge_Message( $watcher, $email, $watch->Subject );

$message = "To: $email\n" . "Subject: $subject\n\n" . $message;

$smtp->data;
$smtp->datasend("$message");
$smtp->dataend;
$smtp->quit;
```