# How to use a SMTP in an html contact form?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, smtp, contact-form

I have the following contact form:

```html
<div class="container red_layer_footer">
<form action="/var/www/cgi-bin/FormMail.pl" method="POST">
<input type=hidden name="recipient" value="mymail@gmail.com">
<input type=hidden name="subject" value="Nuova mail">
<input type=hidden name="redirect" value="http://www.evogale.it/grazie.html">

<h2>CONTATTI</h2>

<div class="name">
<label for="name"></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="name" id="name_input" required>
</div>

<div class="email">
<label for="email"></label>
<input type="email" placeholder="Mail" name="email" id="email_input" required>
</div>

<div class="message">
<label for="message"></label>
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Messaggio" id="message_input" cols="30" rows="5" required></textarea>
</div>

<div class="submit">
<input type="submit" value="Invia Messaggio" id="form_button">
</div>

<input type=hidden name="required" value="email,name,message">
</form> <!-- // End form -->
</div> <!-- End #container -->
```

In an html file, and I want it to send email via an SMTP. How should i modify the code to make that happen? Looking around on the web I've seen that I might add some jQuery code?

Comment: You can't send an email from a browser. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript

Comment: I can see that your backend is Perl CGI script, you might just want to use a Perl module like [`Email::Sender::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Sender::Simple) to send the emails. Some stock-standard approaches are in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008277/sending-mail-via-smtp-in-perl).

Answer (score 1):

To be able to send emails, you need to provide the correct `SMTP` server when you set up your email client. Most of the internet systems use `SMTP` as a method to transfer mail from one user to another. It is a push protocol. In order to use SMTP you need to configure your Gmail. You need to change two settings of your `gmail` account from which you are sending the mail i.e.

**1.** Revoke 2-step verification

**2.** Enabling less secure apps to access Gmail. You can easily do this by clicking on the link [Enable](https://myaccount.google.com/intro/security)

After this just create a html file and include SMTP in your  tag :

```
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>
```

Below is the html code which you will need to run in order to send the mail.

```
    <script src= 
        "https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"> 
      </script> 
      
      <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function sendEmail() { 
          Email.send({ 
            Host: "smtp.gmail.com", 
            Username: "sender@email_address.com", 
            Password: "Enter your password", 
            To: 'receiver@email_address.com', 
            From: "sender@email_address.com", 
            Subject: "Sending Email using javascript", 
            Body: "Well that was easy!!", 
          }) 
            .then(function (message) { 
              alert("mail sent successfully") 
            }); 
        } 
      </script> 
<body> 
  <form method="post"> 
    <input type="button" value="Send Email" 
        onclick="sendEmail()" /> 
  </form> 
</body>
```

**NOTE :** `Best` and `Secure` way to use above method with `SecureToken`  as above method is for understanding purpose, above approach is `highly insecure` as it exposes `credentials` to the users , for how to enable `Security`  you can check this https://smtpjs.com/

Comment: This approach is highly insecure as it exposes credentials to the client.

Comment: @costaparas  there is another way with `SecureToken ` , you can also check https://smtpjs.com/

Comment: 'We've thought of that, so instead you can encrypt your SMTP credentials, and lock it to a single domain, and pass a secure token instead of the credentials instead'

Comment: I have my doubts with routing this through their API endpoint `https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtpjs.aspx`, they're not a well-known or reputable service as far as I'm aware.

Comment: The smtp is not going to be google, tho. Is the code still valid? If so, how can I place the content of the fields in the email? Thanks

Comment: Yes, if your `From Email id` is from Gmail then you have to follow above 2 steps , else you can also use this code with different email id , and you can set value or email content in `body` ,-> `Body: "Well that was easy!!`",

Comment: For Example :- `var name=document.getElementById("name").value` Get value using this and set in `Body`;

Comment: and you have to find `Host` if you are using another host , like `yahoo` have  `smtp.mail.yahoo.com`

Comment: @Brandolo is it useful to you ?

Comment: Hi @Dhrumilshah, I've tried it by just copy-pasting your code on the page, to see if the email would work, but it won't.. I'm currently checking for errors